# Unique Codes - Given to two users who hit script in same second

Tags: php, magento, locking, queue

Hi have a bunch of unique codes in a database which should only be used once.

Two users hit a script which assigns them at the same time and got the same codes!

The script is in Magento and the user can order multiple codes. The issue is if one customer orders 1000 codes the script grabs the top 1000 codes from the DB into an array and then runs through them setting them to "Used" and assigning them to an order. If a second user hits the same script at a similar time the script then grabs the top 1000 codes in the DB at that point in time which crosses over as the first script hasn't had a chance to finish assigning them.

This is unfortunate but has happened quite a few times!

My idea was to create a new table, once the user hits the script a row is made with "order_id" "code_type". Then in the same script a check is done so if a row is in this new table and the "code_type" matches that of which the user is ordering it will wait 60 seconds and check again until the previous codes are issued and the table is empty where it will then create a row and off it goes.

I am not sure if this is the best way or if two users hit at the same second again whether two rows will just be inserted and off we go with the same problem!

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer depends on the database you use.

For example in MySQL with InnoDB the possible solution is a transaction with `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE`.

Schematically it works this by firing following queries:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM codes WHERE used = 0 LIMIT 1000 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
// save ids
UPDATE codes SET used=1 WHERE id IN ( ...ids....);
COMMIT;
```

More information at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Why not `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`?

Comment: @syck Because in this case they are locked only from other `update`s. `Select`s will returns these (locked) rows, giving problems, for example if it is first checked whether there are enough codes to fulfill an order...

Comment: If the rows are locked, will another query simply not try to use them automatically or will I have to do a condition to skip them?

Comment: As far as I understand it, it will wait until the transaction is ended.

Comment: This has been useful, I have moved this question to the Magento section for help using built in magento functions for this. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97410/begin-commit-lock-rows-to-prevent-user-from-receiving-same-code

Comment: @KiwisTasteGood As I could judge, what you in Magento is not really equal to what I suggested. To use `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` you should fire custom query, Zend Framework can not do it for you out of the box.

Comment: Thanks I will look into using a custom query as you have stated, thanks!